# Given a Laravel 5 Eloquent model, how can I update all models on a relationship in one query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model Company which hasMany Jobs. Company and Job represent mysql tables.

Simplified class here:

```
class Company extends Eloquent
{
   public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Job');
    }
}
```

I want to add a function to this class to deactivate all the company's jobs by setting the `is_active` property on each job to `0`. With the query builder I could accomplish this with one simple update query. Is there a way to do this using the models/relationships in one query instead of iterating through every job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$company = Company::first(); // Or some $company where you want to update the jobs
$company->jobs()->update(['is_active' => 0]);
```

If you call `$company->jobs()` it will return the query object and you can chain query methods on it.

Then the method would look like this:

```
public function deactivateJobs()
{
    return $this->jobs()->update(['is_active' => 0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's no reason why you can't use the Job model inside the Company model. Would something like this work for you?

```
public function deactivateJobs()
{
    App\Model\Job::where('company_id', $this->id)->update(['is_active' => false]);
}
```